# How to hide .html extension from the website url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I know this question has been asked before but does anyone know of a good way to hide .html extensions. I've tried many of codes & many of the answers from the https://stackoverflow.com/ but am not seeing the result. Thats y I ask u again

I've a static website and I wanted to remove the extension to clean my urls. I was working with static html files.

Prior to removing the extension, the url would read `website.com/about.html`.

With the extension removed, it would look like website.com/about. Hope that was clear.

I've a .htaccess file and I tried many of the codes but it dosen't work. Here are some codes

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301] 



RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /(.+/)?index(\.html)?(\?.*)?\  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+/)?index(\.html)?$ /%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [QSA,L]



RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,L]



RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]



RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html


RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm$ $1.html [nc]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule !.*\.html$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html [L]
```

however I am not seeing any results...:(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have your rule reversed (the first one would work otherwise):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L]
```

Your original rule was `RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1 [L]` which translates to "If the requested resource name ends with `.html` then issue a redirect to the browser telling it to ask us if we have anything at the same name without the HTML".  This results in a 404 (since Apache doesn't have anything to serve for the `.html`'less resource).

By switching the `.html` to the destination `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L]` we change the rule to say "If the requested resource name is not a file or directory on disk then try to re-route the request (internally, don't tell the browser) as if it ended in `.html`".

Answer (score 1):

Note that you do not need complex (by nature) RewriteRules for such task.

The **mod_negotiation** apache module, often enabled by default, provides such behavior with [Multivews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_negotiation.html#multiviews) option.

> If the server receives a request for /some/dir/foo and /some/dir/foo does not exist, then the server reads the directory looking for all files named foo.*, and effectively fakes up a type map which names all those files, assigning them the same media types and content-encodings it would have if the client had asked for one of them by name. It then chooses the best match to the client's requirements, and returns that document.

.i.e requesting for `foo/bar` will serve `foo/bar` if it us a directory and will seak for `foo/bar.html`, `foo/bar.txt` and such etc if not.

You just need to ensure this option is activated in your current context (a Directory for example)

```
Options +Multiviews
```

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at this post http://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/ I haven't tried it yet but the demonstration seems pretty convincing