# Should I use an .htaccess file on a static HTML site?

Tags: .htaccess, static, url-rewriting

Should I use an .htaccess file on a static HTML site? I want to hide .html extension from the url. Many of the code I've tried but none them are working.

http://eisabainyo.net/weblog/2007/08/19/removing-file-extension-via-htaccess/

[How to hide .html extension from the website url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13853788/how-to-hide-html-extension-from-the-website-url)

Anybody please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not working maybe because the AllowOverwrite directive is not properly set : see [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride)

You should increase the log level with [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteloglevel) to see what happens.